# php/jQuery get primary key for selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get key(primary key) for selected value in my form, so I can add key into joining table. I change my form to autocomplete from  drop down list. but do not how to do map with jquery.

This is my php for autocomplete

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'faculty_id') {

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $nameID = $_POST['nameID'];


    $query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, FacultyId FROM Test.Faculty where UPPER(FirstName) LIKE '" . strtoupper($name) . "%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'];
        $nameID = $row['FacultyId'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);


    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
?>
```

this is form and jQuery page

```
<form action="Form.php" method="post">
    <input type='text'  id="faculty_id" placeholder="Instructor" name="faculty_id" value='' />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#faculty_id').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Form.php',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term,
                    nameID: request.term,
                    type: 'faculty_id'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        //var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item,
                            data: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,

    });
</script>
```

and php insert query

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $faculty_id = $_POST['faculty_id'];
    try {
        $stat = $db->prepare("Insert into ATCTest.Schedule
                      (Faculty ) 
                      VALUE (':faculty_id' )");
        $stat->bindParam(":faculty_id", $faculty_id);

        if ($stat->execute()) {
            echo "<h5>Faculty-js: " . $faculty_id . "</h5>";
        } else {
            echo "Problem!!!";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stay consistent. Choose either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Not both. Your autocomplete script uses MySQLi, but then in your insert script, you use PDO. Pick one and stick with it.

I'll use PDO as I find it much easier to use than MySQLi.

2. Use the appropriate request methods. If you are getting something, use GET not POST. If you are adding or updating, use POST.

Let's rewrite your autocomplete script to use PDO:

```
    if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'faculty_id') {
        // this will hold your response that gets sent back
        $data = null;
        $name = trim($_GET['name']);

        try {
            // because you are passed untrusted data, use prepared statement 
            $sth = $db->prepare("
                SELECT FirstName, LastName, FacultyId 
                FROM Test.Faculty 
                WHERE UPPER(FirstName) LIKE UPPER(?)
            ");
            $sth->execute(array($name . '%'));
            // set the results (array of objects) as your JSON response
            $data['faculties'] = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        // send the results i.e. response
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
```

2. I've never used the autocomplete plugin before but I'll take a crack at it based on other answers I've seen.

   ```
   $('#faculty_id').autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           // short syntax for .ajax() using GET method that expects a JSON response
           $.getJSON('Form.php', { type: 'faculty_id', name: request.term }, function (data) {
               // data.faculties (your AJAX script's response) should now be an array of objects
               console.log(data.faculties);
               response($.map(data.faculties, function (faculty) {
                   console.log(faculty);
                   return {
                       label: faculty.FirstName + ' ' + faculty.LastName,
                       value: faculty.FacultyId
                   }
               }));
           });
       },
       autoFocus: true,
       minLength: 1,
   });
   ```
3. Lastly, when you insert

   ```
   // check if form was POSTed
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       $faculty_id = $_POST['faculty_id'];
       try {
           // VALUES not VALUE
           // don't wrap your placeholders with quotes in your prepared statement
           // simplified
           $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ATCTest.Schedule(Faculty) VALUES(?)");
           // simplified way to bind parameters
           $sth->execute(array($faculty_id));
           // use rowCount() not execute() to determine if the operation was successful or not
           if ($sth->rowCount()){
               echo "<h5>Faculty-js: $faculty_id</h5>";
           } else {
               echo "Problem!!!";
           }
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Mikey, but autocomplete is not working. it does not give any error also.

Comment: Check my last edit for a typo. [Turn on your PHP errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) if you haven't done so. Pinpoint where the problem exactly occurs: "is it JS or PHP or both?" Start with the JS by opening your browser's developer tool (Chrome has a beautiful interface for this): check the console logs for any outputs; check the Network tab (XHR) and look at the request and response being sent when you key in data. After doing all that, clarify what you mean by _autocomplete is not working_.

Comment: it's working, but it show value(facultyId) after selecting label(name). and its JS error. I did not know about turn on errors php.ini,  will look more for JS autocomplete.